# Jest component test throws unexpected character '�' error

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, jestjs, babeljs

I'm trying to run component tests on a PWA made with Vue 2 and Webpack. When I try to run them I get an error saying unexpected character '�' and this prevents me from doing the tests I want.
[image: Error screenshot]
The Login.test.js file is:

```
 import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
 import Login from "../../src/views/Login.vue";
 
 describe("Login.test.js", () => {
 let cmp
 
 beforeEach(() => {
 cmp = shallowMount(Login, {
 Create a shallow instance of the component
 data: {
 messages: ["Cat"]
       }
     });
   });
 
 it('equals messages to ["Cat"]', () => {
 expect(cmp.vm.messages).toEqual(["Cat"]);
   });
 });
```

The package.json of my project is the following:

```
{
  "name": "mobile-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --dest dist && workbox injectManifest && node src/swEnvBuild.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^2.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.0.1",
    "c3": "^0.6.8",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^1.2.0",
    "compressorjs": "^1.1.1",
    "countries-and-timezones": "^3.3.0",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "firebase": "^7.21.1",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "google-maps": "^3.3.0",
    "influx": "^5.4.0",
    "jest-vue-preprocessor": "^1.7.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^1.28.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "npm": "^6.10.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.5.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-datetime": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.24.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.14",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-persist": "^3.1.3",
    "weekstart": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.7.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "copyfiles": "^1.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.1.6",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
    "web-push": "^3.3.3",
    "workbox-cli": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "vue"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-vue-preprocessor"
    },
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
      "customExportConditions": [
        "node",
        "node-addons"
      ]
    },
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test/setEnvVars.js"
    ]
  },
  "presets": [
[
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "last 2 versions",
            "ie >= 11"
          ]
        },
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

My webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./app.vue"],
module: {
rules: [
      {
test: /\.jsx?$/,
exclude: ['node_modules'],
use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
test: /\.css$/,
use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
    ],
  },
resolve: {
extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
modules: [
      'node_modules'
    ]
  }
};
```

My babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
};
```

And my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", {
    "targets": {
      "node": "current"
    }
  }]],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx"]
}
```

I guess it's a problem with babel or jest utils dependencies but I couldn't fix it.

I've tried adjusting the dependency versions and following the Jest documentation but nothing works for me. What I hope is to be able to run the isolated component tests.